Looking for ideas about storage space access in attic
In the attic of my house, the volume where the roof comes close to the attic floor is arranged as a storage space. I don't know the term for this but it's very common where I live and I found some pictures online that perfectly show the setup (not my attic, but close to identical):
https://static.tosize.com/General/DIY/DIY-24603/image-thumb__14673__nl_nl_watermark_scale_by_width_1280/KLUS-24603_Multiplex-Interieur-Populier-Gegrond-scaled.webp
https://static.tosize.com/General/DIY/DIY-24603/image-thumb__14672__nl_nl_watermark_scale_by_width_1280/KLUS-24603_Multiplex-Interieur-Populier-Gegrond-4-scaled-e1612787904254.webp
Just like in the second picture above, I have this in two areas of my attic, the storage space is hidden by thin wooden panels which are screwed directly into the top wooden beam.
Everytime I want to access the storage space, I have to unscrew and then screw back through the (hole in the) panel and into the wood. I find that damaging to the thin wooden beam (if I don't align the panels perfectly) and also kind of a hack. Additionally on one side I have 6 panels of about 50 cm width that are each screwed with one screw into the beam, but on the other side I have a single wide panel  that is screwed with 6 screws into the beam (so much more hassle to access that space).
I would like to do a slightly better hack and am looking for some ideas about how to secure these panels to the beam to provide easier access and without damaging the beam on every access and preferably without extra tools or wooden materials. Slightly unrelated, I have a 3d printer and would like to print whatever fittings/connetors are needed just for fun (this is a "nice to have", not a requirement).
A few ideas that came to my mind are:

Printing handles and some parts that can screw magnet holders to the back of the panel and the bottom of the top beam ; hopefully this would just keep the panel in place. That would be easiest to access, no change to the beam after the initial install. Assuming this works, one downside to this is that the previous owners have run a plastic electrical conduit behind the beam (with live wires in it) for power in the attic and I have a very small child that could one day venture out to try the magnetic doors and be exposed to electrocution risk.
With the problem I see above, then I thought maybe it would be nice to have a lock on the panels, like a mailbox lock. I could print a sort of a cuboid that is thin in one dimension and wide in another and have a turning locking arm hold against it when locked. Sounds a bit fishy and in this case the panels will probably not close tightly against the beam/frame so there would be some wiggle.
I could install some vertical posts from the top beam to the ground, and just put hinges and normal locks on the panels.

So thank you for reading my long story so far. My queston is: does anyone see some very common fastener/connector idea that I am completely missing? Ideally it would adapt to the already available panels, I have no problem trying to copy the design and print it, or buy it if that fails.
Thank you very much

supermagnets might be useful for this

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Replace with plastic accordion door or with a few hinged doors on new posts.

jsotola and jay613 , thank you both for the responses!
